# Contemporary Abstract Algebra (External Direct Products):

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My question is from the book *(Contemporary Abstract Algebra)* in chapter 8 exercise 8:

> Prove that $S_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_4 \times Z_3$.

If anyone if may can help me with this problem I will appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what property do you think Isomorphism preserve?? you should see some thing by definition itself (bijection)....

Comment: Welcome to math.SE.  Please try to typeset your questions using MathJax (simple LaTeX markup).  Here's a quick tutorial of the basics:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Praphulla, these two groups have the same number of elements.

Comment: I did not said that counting will suffice but, i was telling basic criterion for isomorphic groups as an example..

Comment: It's always a good idea to write down the author's name. In this case I think it is Gallian...?

Comment: I am afraid It is not fruitful to discuss hints and write answers when the Person who has asked this question is not responding...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264096/when-are-c-2-times-c-2-rtimes-c-3-rtimes-c-2-and-c-2-times-c-2-rt

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

-- All the element's in $\;D_4\;$ have order $\;1,2\;\text{or}\;4\;$

-- How many elements of order three does $\;D_4\times C_3\;$ have, and how many $\;S_4\;$ has?

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that two groups are **not** isomorphic, you want to find a property that is preserved by isomorphisms, and yet, differs between the two groups.  Some examples:  the existence of elements of certain orders, the existence of subgroups of certain orders, the number of elements of a certain order.

One possible way:  look at the center of $S_4$ and compare it to the center of $D_3 \times Z_3$.   (In particular, compare their sizes.)

Answer (score 1):

Considering @Don's post, you can see that the equation $x^2=e$ has different number of solutions in both groups.For example, regarding to $D_8$'s presentation; the following elements are from order $2$:

$$b, a^2,ab,a^2b,a^3b$$

But, clearly, in $S_4$ we face the following:

$$(3,4),~ (2,3),~ (2,4),~ (1,2),~ (1,2)(3,4),~ (1,3),~ (1,3)(2,4),~ (1,4), ~
  (1,4)(2,3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the commutator subgroup or center at both sides:

$S_4^{'} \cong A_4$ and $(D_4 \times C_3){'} \cong C_2 \times \{1\} \cong C_2$

$Z(S_4)=\{(1)\}$ and $Z(D_4 \times C_3) \cong Z(D_4) \times Z(C_3) \cong C_2 \times C_3 \cong C_6$

Answer (score 1):

This is high-powered but makes the subgroup structure of $S_4$ very transparent: Let $C$ be a unit cube centered at the origin in $\mathbf{R}^3$ and consider the subgroup of $SO(3)$ which preserves $C$. This is the orientation-preserving isometry group (or, in short, the symmetry group) of the cube, let us call it $\text{Isom}(C)$. There is an action of $\text{Isom}(C)$ on the four diagonals of the cube which you can check is transitive and free. The permutation representation gives an isomorphism $\text{Isom}(C) \cong S_4$.

Consider one of the three pairs of opposite faces of $C$, say the top $t$ and the bottom face $b$, and consider the subgroup of $\text{Isom}(C)$ which stabilizes the unordered pair $\{t, b\}$. This consists of the four rotations along the axis of $C$ passing through the midpoints of $t$ and $b$ (these fix $t$ and $b$ pointwise), and the four rotations by angle $\pm \pi$ along the two other axes passing through midpoints of opposite faces (these switch $t$ and $b$). To be concise, this group is generated by $r$ (rotation by $\pi/2$ along $z$-axis) and $s$ (rotation by $\pi$ along $x$-axis). It can be easily checked that $r^4 = s^2 = 1$ and $srs = r^{-1}$, so $\langle r, s \rangle < \text{Isom}(C)$ is isomorphic to $D_8$.

The three pairs of opposite faces gives rise to three subgroups of $\text{Isom}(C)$ isomorphic to $D_8$ and they are all conjugate as the faces of a cube can be relabelled by an isometry so that any pair of opposite faces is $\{t, b\}$ after relabelling. This means $S_4$ has three conjugate $D_8$'s: indeed, these are precisely the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4$ ($n_2 = 3$) and all of them are conjugate by Sylow theory. These exhaust all the subgroups of order $8$ in $S_4$, so none of them are normal. However $D_8 \times \Bbb Z_3$ clearly has a normal $D_8$ in it.

You can understand more about the structure of these Sylow $2$-subgroups by inspecting the cube: notice that these three $D_8$'s intersect in a $V_4$ containing the identity and rotation by $\pi$ along $x$-axis, $y$-axis and $z$-axis respectively. In particular this $V_4 < \text{Isom}(C) \cong S_4$ is normal: explicitly, it consists of the double transpotions in $S_4$ (you can easily read that off from what it does to the diagonals of $C$), and they form a conjugacy class. Since each of the three $D_8$ stabilizes a pair of opposite faces of the cube, $V_4$ stabilizes all three pairs. By orbit-stabilizer theorem, $S_4/V_4$ is the symmetry group on the three pairs of opposite faces of $C$, hence is isomorphic to $S_3$. This is one of the exceptional homomorphisms $S_4 \to S_3$.

In fact I think similar arguments involving the dodecahedron gives the exceptional embedding $S_5 \to S_6$: realize $A_5$ as the group of orientation-preserving isometries of the dodecahedron $D$. In this case, you work with embedded squares in the dodecahedron instead of diagonals:

[image]

It can be checked that there are five distinct embedded such cubes, on which the group of rotations of the dodecahedron act freely (alternatively, the class equation of $\text{Isom}(D)$ can be checked to be $60 = 1 +$ $15 + 20 + 12 + 12$, and there is no way to club the terms, including $1$, to get a divisor of $60$. This proves the simplicity of $\text{Isom}(D)$, so kernel of the action has to be trivial). The permutation representation gives an embedding $\text{Isom}(D) \to S_5$ into a subgroup of order $60$ in $S_5$, which can only be $A_5$.

Once that is done, note that $\text{Isom}(D)$ similarly acts on the six pairs of opposite faces of the dodecahedron, giving a permutation representation $A_5 \to S_6$. Note how the 3-cycles of $A_5$, corresponding to rotation along an axis through two opposite vertices of the dodecahedron, permutes two pairs of three opposite faces, so are mapped to $3+3$-cycles under this embedding. This is starting to look like the exceptional automorphism of $S_6$ (which represents the nontrivial element in $\text{Out}(S_6) = \text{Aut}(S_6)/\text{Inn}(S_6)$ and is exceptional in the sense $\text{Out}(S_n)$ is the trivial group for every $n > 2$ except $n = 6$), which takes the conjugacy class of $3$-cycles to the conjugacy class of $3+3$-cycles. Perhaps there's a way to naturally extend the map to the standard exceptional embedding $S_5 \to S_6$. Note that algebraically that can also be obtained from Sylow theory, as $n_5 = 6$ for $S_5$, and $S_5$ acts on these six Sylow $5$-subgroups by conjugation, analogous to the picture for cubes.